# How to assign the return of the readAsLines() to a local List in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I have just written this code:

```
Future<List<String>> readMedsNames() async{

   List<String> medsNames;
   final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   File eventFilePointer = File('${directory.path}/events.txt');

   if(eventFilePointer.existsSync()){

      eventFilePointer.readAsLines().then((lines) =>
         print(lines) //Works
         //medsNames = lines
      ); //Doesn't work, when I print it in the flollowing line the value is null...
      //print(medsNames);
      return medsNames;
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

I have to return the `List<String>` filled with all the lines written in the file I had read.
How can I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the data/text structure of events.txt?

Comment: NomeMedicina_1§LunMarMerGioVenSabDom§15.30\n
NomeMedicina_2§LunMarMerGioVenSabDom§15.30\n
NomeMedicina_3§LunMarMerGioVenSabDom§15.30\n
NomeMedicina_4§LunMarMerGioVenSabDom§15.30\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `return` statement hit before, `async` callback finish. Try like below:

```
if(eventFilePointer.existsSync()) {
   medsNames = await eventFilePointer.readAsLines();
   print(medsNames);
   return medsNames;
}
return null;
```

Comment: @Lucasal2001 Great to here about it! Note that when you dealt with `async` with `.then()`, the line after that will invoke after executing the `then()`. You can test that by adding simple `print` statement inside `then()` and after `then()`. Read more here: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Future/then.html